# d3js display only path elements contained in bounding box

Tags: d3.js, svg, topojson

I have two topojson files obtained from shapefiles which I append to the same `g` node of an svg element in a nested loop.

```
// Layer 1
d3.json("grid.topojson", function(error, grid) {

  // Layer 2 (continents)
  d3.json("continents.topojson", function(error, continent) {

  ...
```

It is possible to click on the continents to zoom in on a particular region (from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541).

The grid layer is very dense so it slows down the zoom when clicking on the continents in the continent layer. To get around this, I would like to display the grid layer only after zooming in on a particular continent. I have an `.on("click")` event that triggers the zoom function:

```
function clicked(path, d, m_width, m_height, _this, grid) {

        var this_class = get_classFromPath(_this);

        var bounds = path.bounds(d),
          dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
          dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
          x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
          y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
          scale = .2 / Math.max(dx / m_width, dy / m_height),
          translate = [m_width / 2 - scale * x, m_height / 2 - scale * y];

        g.transition()
          .duration(750)
          .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + "px")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
          // .selectAll("path.model-grid")
          // .style("display", "inline");
      }
```

In the `clicked` function, I want to make the grid visible after the zoom, but it seems unnecessary (and is very slow) to use`selectAll` since only a small part of the total grid is visible in the display. Unfortunately, the shapefile of the grid does not contain any ids I can use to correlate with the id of the continents, so I cannot select grid path elements by id.

Is there a way to find out which path elements of the grid layer are contained in the `bounds` box after the zoom?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!